# cakephp update record with non-id unique field

Tags: cakephp

I am working on a project in CakePHP.

When we want to update a record in database, we generally do:

```
$save_arr = array('field1'=>'value1');
$this->MyModel->id = $id;
$this->MyModel->save($save_arr);
```

I am in a situation where I am updating some data with Ajax and I am only passing the field name (field1), its new value (value1) and value of another field that will be unique in my table (say 'myUniqueField' with value 12). **I DO NOT get the value of "id" field here.**

How can I update my record using this non-id field, which will be unique.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `updateAll()` method:

```
$this->Model->updateAll(
    array('Model.field1' => "'value1'"), // Watch out! Manual escaping here!
    array('Model.MyUniqueField' => 12)
);
```

Comment: can you do a deleteAll in the same way?